# css menu under Google Ads?

Tags: html, css

I have a weird effect :

[image]

As you can see, the menu goes under the Google banner. I am searching something that could put the menu over the banner. You can see this effet live at : [www.forexvirtuel.com](http://www.forexvirtuel.com).

The code look like:

```
...
<div id="navigation">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="page_item page-item-26"><a href="http://www.forexvirtuel.com/les-calculs/" title="Les calculs">Les calculs</a>
        <ul>

            <li class="page_item page-item-33"><a href="http://www.forexvirtuel.com/les-calculs/calcul-du-rollover/" title="Calcul du Rollover">Calcul du Rollover</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-31"><a href="http://www.forexvirtuel.com/les-calculs/calculs-des-gains-et-calculs-pertes/" title="Calculs des gains et calculs pertes">Calculs des gains et calculs pertes</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-29"><a href="http://www.forexvirtuel.com/les-calculs/prix-d%e2%80%99un-pip-prix-d%e2%80%99un-point/" title="Prix d’un pip (prix d’un point)">Prix d’un pip (prix d’un point)</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="navigation_pub">
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "pub-0909660115587797";
    /* Forex_Header */
    google_ad_slot = "6839564983";
    google_ad_width = 728;
    google_ad_height = 90;
    //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script>
</div>
...
```

Css:

```
#navigation
{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 930px;
    background-image: url(images/header.gif);
    height: 56px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

#navigation_pub
{
    clear: both;
    height: 90px;
    width: 930px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:1px;
}
```

Any idea how to put the menu over the banner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, near as I can tell, the ads appear later in the DOM and so naturally cover the popup list. You should be able to override this using `z-index`:

```
#nav li ul { z-index: 1; }
```

Comment: +1 and the accepted answer. You got it right about the loading order and your solution works. Thank you very much.